# How to combine multiple arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to combine some multiple arrays into one array.

I tried _.zip of **lodash** library, but that's not what I want.

Here is the arrays:

```
var arr1 = [
    'a', 'b'
];
var arr2 = [
    'c', 'd'
];
var arr3 = [
    'e'
];
```

And I want this output:

```
var result = [
    ['a', 'c', 'e'],
    ['a', 'd', 'e'],
    ['b', 'c', 'e'],
    ['b', 'd', 'e']
];
```

Comment: Three nested loops would accomplish this.

Comment: Does it need to work for an arbitrary number of starting arrays?

Comment: I found this gist that uses lodash that you may find useful. https://gist.github.com/wassname/a882ac3981c8e18d2556 Use the combination function with a spread of the 3 arrays `combinations([...a1, ...a2, ...a3], 3)`. Or the Cartesian product like the other person said.

Comment: What you're looking for is called "Cartesian product". There are solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @RobG the thread I linked has many answers, most of them not using any external libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function for a cartesian product of the given arrays.

```js
const cartesian = (...p) =>
        p.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

var a = ['a', 'b'],
    b = ['c', 'd'],
    c = ['e'];
    result = cartesian(a, b, c);

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you expect to always have the same number of arrays, I find this more readable though a bit redundant:

```js
let arr1 = [
  'a', 'b'
];
let arr2 = [
  'c', 'd'
];
let arr3 = [
  'e'
];

let result = arr1.flatMap(one =>
    arr2.flatMap(two =>
        arr3.map(three => [one, two, three])));
console.log(result);
```

If you're not always expecting 3 arrays or prefer a generic func to multiply an arbitrary number of arrays:

```js
let arr1 = [
  'a', 'b'
];
let arr2 = [
  'c', 'd'
];
let arr3 = [
  'e'
];

let multiply = (...arrays) =>
    arrays.reduce((results, array) =>
        results.flatMap(result => array.map(a => [...result, a])), ['']);

let results = multiply(arr1, arr2, arr3);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: The second one doesn't work. `...result` is actually spreading a string. Since this has strings with single character, it works. If you try with `[
  'aa', 'bb'
]` you can see it

Comment: good catch. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, this is called the Cartesian Product of your arrays.  I find it easier to build it by folding (`reducing`) over one that takes the product of two arrays.

```js
const product = (xs, ys) => 
  xs .flatMap (x => ys .map (y => [x, y] .flat () ) )

const productAll = (...xss) => 
  xss .reduce (product)

console .log (
  productAll ( ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'])
)
```

If your environment doesn't [support `flat` and `flatmap`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-flat), they are pretty easy to shim.

If you want to supply the arrays inside one array `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e']]` instead of separately, just replace `...xss` with `xss`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple people have alread mentioned that your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript). So, you might want to have a look there for a recommended solution.

I just wanted to add another functional solution which can be arbitrarily combined. The `listProduct` function in this case has type `listProduct :: [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]` meaning it takes a (at least) 2-dimensional array as its first argument and returns one. That's why the `singletonize` function is required to convert the first array into a 2-dimensional array.

As shown below you can easily combine calls to this function to get a product of n (n ≥ 2) list if you want.

```js
const singletonize = l => l.map(x => [x])
const listProduct = (ls, list) => 
  ls.reduce((r, l) => {
      combinations = list.map(x => l.concat(x))
      return r.concat(combinations)
  }, [])
  
// The three arrays of your example
const a_1 = ['a', 'b'];
const a_2 = ['c', 'd'];
const a_3 = ['e'];
console.log(listProduct(listProduct(singletonize(a_1), a_2), a_3))

// Another example with five arrays
const a_4 = ['f', 'g', 'h'];
const a_5 = ['i'];

console.log(listProduct(listProduct(listProduct(listProduct(singletonize(a_1), a_2), a_3), a_4), a_5))
```